# fedex-Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, fedex

I set up fedex in magento

I am using the fedex credentials 
 I got error as **Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.**
am using 
**651 Roosevelt St
Apt 1A
San Juan PR**
this address for checking .please help me.

Comment: and in admin side i fill up account no,meter no,key & password  for fedex shipping method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi my problem is with server. server request is not connected to fedex .our company server is request restricted by admin person .you can check log /shipping_fedex file. if

[result] => 
Array
        (
            [error] => looks like we got no XML document
            [code] => 0
        )

this indicate that your request is not reach to fedex .thank you all for support.

Answer (score 0):

FedEx considers PR as the state code and US as the Country code (UPS uses PR as a country code) did you use US as country code or PR? It might be your issue.

Comment: I fill shipping address =St. Mary's Plaza Norte, 1485 Avenida Ashford then city=Avenida Ashford  San Juan    then  state=PR and country=US and postal code=00907 still i got same problem

Comment: is it successful for a US to US quote? (not PR)

Comment: Sometimes FedEx doesn't give the best error messages. Make sure you have included a service type (try 01 for Priority) a package type (try 01) a weight in pounds, and a billing type (1 for bill sender). International shipments may also want some customs info, but I would start with US to US first and see if you get a result

Comment: after i check in log file i give this error     [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => looks like we got no XML document
            [code] => 0
        ) what means it.